# Can't debug my ts-node express project (Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found)

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

I'll use this project [express-typescript-starter](https://github.com/rjmacarthy/express-typescript-starter), but when I put the breakpoint and started debug on VS Code he said "Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found (source map problem?)."

launch.json

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\index.js",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
    },
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach to Process",
        "port": 5858
    }
]
```

tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "listFiles": false
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be necessary tasks.json using the tsc to generate the files JS and JS.MAP. But I don't know why because I put the break point on TS files and works to me...

```
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "tsc",
"isShellCommand": true,
"args": ["-p", "."],
"showOutput": "silent",
"problemMatcher": "$tsc"
```

Repository with the solution:

`https://github.com/bsalesc/express-typescript-starter/`